# Better to check username and password or just username?

Tags: authentication, passwords, while-loop

When a user tries to log in, there are two ways to check if the user is valid or not.

Method 1: Perform the following query and check the number of returned rows is identical to 1.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_POST['username'] AND password = md5($_POST['password'])
```

Method 2: Perform the query, then check the passwords match.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_POST['username']

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if($row['password'] == md5($_POST['password'])) $logged_in = TRUE;
}
```

Is one of these methods preferred over the other? And if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a key, salt and the password. `md5` is not secure.

On the server, you store a key:

```
$key = 'fPu6AY;h0-5Q>cIel,@n2$gickGs9{ys~+DT,v|Mz-]~EU3tuj18|~Ch#1_$)fGR';
```

A *unique* salt is generated when the user is registered and is stored on the server along with the encrypted password:

```
|       SALT |                                                         PASSWORD |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| jAcTgi~4(Z | 877236d15a7b7a1f36febc49e58b142d70d72cf7d6e54dcfb252d7cde6b62a2d |
```

The password is encrypted like so:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $keyFromServer . $saltFromDb . $userPassword);
```

You must then use method 2 to fetch the salt and hash to compare it to the database password.

Comment: But assuming I use a key, hash and salt, is method 1 or method 2 preferable?

Comment: You would need to use method 2 to fetch the salt.

Comment: But I couldn't I still use Method 1 eg..." WHERE username = $_POST['username'] AND password = hashed_salted_password($_POST['password'])", where that function does the work for me?

Comment: hashed_salted_password($password) could be a function that both salts and hashes my password...

Comment: Ah sorry - you're saying every user should have their own salt?

Comment: @Lars See my updated answer. You need the salt from the database.

Comment: @Lars - Most databases do not offer appropriate functions to hash passwords (even SHA256 should not be used). That means, you _cannot_ use the hash function inside an SQL-statement, you need to get the hash-value first and then call the hash function via code. To hash passwords, one should use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt with a cost factor.

Answer (score 2):

Method 2 is preferred because you can then use libraries like PHPass. It also gives you the ability to tell a user that they typed an invalid username instead of having them guess if they mistyped one or the other. Aarolama is right about md5 not being secure. Unfortunately, neither is the SHA series. Both of those are file hashes, used for uniquely labeling and identifying files. Use a crypto hash to secure a password, one like blowfish. PHPass handles a lot of the security for you. Salts should be randomly generated and unique for each user, and the only way to get them for your own use is through the second method.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the *FreshPrinceOfSO*'s answer, don't simply concatenate the secret key with the salted plaintext — use HMAC approach instead:

```php
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $saltFromDb . $userPassword, $keyFromServer);
```

Further details on HMAC can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) and [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104), together with explanation on why the trivial approach is flawed. It's also worth to note that HMACs are substantially less affected by collisions than their underlying hashing algorithms alone, i. e. they are more secure despite the same core algorithm and output size.

By the way, regarding the output size. In section 5 of aforementioned RFC 2104, it is stated that truncated hashes (half of original size, or larger), while decrease the total number of possible values, at the same time make it more difficult to recover the plaintext by brute force, as the full hash value to check against becomes unavailable to the attacker. This applies to non-HMAC hashes as well.